# 3d geometry engine

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, geometry

I'm new to processing 3D data with c++ (or c++0x) and I'm trying to write simple application, which will allow to process such data (model, subdivide etc).
I'm searching for something like '3d geometry engine' - engine that handles efficently 3d geometry in memory and gives API to modify its componens (vertexes, points, polygons (not only triangles), attributes of vertexes, etc).
I was searching for something like that, but without luck. Could you recommend any (best open-source) 3D geometry engine, that will have such api, if there is any engine freely available?

Thank you.

Comment: As you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: I cannot selectm more than one answer as correct? So right now I have to examine deeply these 2 libraries - OpenMesh and Cgeo to see which is better lets say designed. I understeand that both of them have similar poly processing features, but I'm wondering which of them is better "designed"

Answer (score 5):

If your main concern is processing polygonal meshes (like your question suggests, although "3d geometry engine" might mean something broader), you can look into [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org). As you mentioned C++0x, I assume you are no enemy with templates, so you might like OpenMesh, as it makes heavy use of generic programming constructs, to make up an easy to use, but still very efficient mesh datastructure. It does not come with too much pre-factured algorithms for mesh processing, but some few that might be a starting point for implementing your own algorithms.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into OpenMesh. Could you tell me if you have any expirenece with [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/project_ideas.html)? Could you compare it to OpenMesh in any terms?

Comment: @danilo2 I don't have any experience with CGAL. It's a huge general computational geometry library that provides much more than just polygonal meshes. I don't know how usable it is, but it's got a large community and is widely used, I think. Maybe pmr knows more about it. But if you're only interrested in polygonal meshes, then OpenMesh is a nice and fast little library.

Comment: @danilo Christian is right. CGAL _is_ huge but the single packages are fairly well separated from each other (besides from the kernels, which are omnipresent). You should get an idea which algorithms you need to use and look for a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) provides a wide variety of mesh processing algorithms and comes with custom number types for exact floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm comparing it right now to other tools and it looks really interesting!:)

Comment: Although it's been quite long since this, I've been recently making the same question. I've seen that basically: CGAL is _HUGE_, so more complex, it includes many pre-built algorithms, but most of them has a GPL license, so for commercial projects with low budget may not be the most convenient. OpenMesh on the other hand is quite simpler, with a flexible license compatible with commercial projects (LPGL) although it has a smaller algorithms library.

Answer (score 3):

You can try http://pointclouds.org/.

According to the website : The Point Cloud Library (or PCL) is a large scale, open project for point cloud processing.

The PCL framework contains numerous state-of-the art algorithms including filtering, feature estimation, surface reconstruction, registration, model fitting and segmentation.

PCL is released under the terms of the BSD license and is open source software. It is free for commercial and research use. We are financially supported by Willow Garage, NVidia, Google, and Toyota.

Comment: If I understand well though, PCL is for point cloud geometry, as opposed to more classic meshes. That's not a problem per-se, it's just something the OP should be aware of.

Comment: great! Thank you very much for that - my question was not connected to this topic, but it will be veru usefull to me!

Answer (score 2):

I have had some success with VTK. It may not be the best API for dealing with meshes, but it works, and has decent functionality for displaying them. And I know at least a few computational geometry guys who work exclusively with it, so it can't be entirely bad :)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look at it! Maybe it willn ot suit my needs (because I want to develop a big application (on the beginning small, but then growing up) and as you told, it could not be the best API. I will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Graphite, an open source geometry processing framework, much easier to handle than CGAL while providing Delaunay etc.
http://alice.loria.fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22

This is definitely more advanced than "just handling triangles and points", but provide interesting often necessary functionnalities for mesh processing.